# How to set the route builder based on condition in camelContext

Tags: apache-camel, spring-bean

In my existing code I am having 2 route builders inside my `camelcontext` bean

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder1" />
  <routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder2" />
</camelContext>
```

I want to set the route builder based on the flag values which is configured in system configuration properties.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why you don't use routes directly? If your goal is to send messages to 2 routes you can use multicast. Not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: @isaac.hazan I want to select the root based on the system properties, So that it will be deployable without generating the war again. Here route 1 and route 2 differs totally by their source and destination end point. Sometimes I may require like both the roots to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could define routeBuilder1.enabled = true in your properties and then use:

```
@Value("${routeBuilder1.enabled}")
private boolean routeEnabled;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("..")
    .autoStartup(routeEnabled)
    .to("...")
}
```

Comment: When I set the value for routeEnabled as false I am getting the below exception 
    Cannot find any routes with this RouteBuilder reference:RouteBuilderRef[routebuilder1]

Comment: Solved that exception [Root cause & Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897726/getting-the-exception-cannot-find-any-routes-with-this-routebuilder-reference)